# Mule 4: SFTP List files that contain a variable

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have an SFTP directory that contains several files in this format

```
19328D_T001045863113302101909_20220721_103898.txt
1932A8_T001045863113302101909_20220721_103802.txt
```

The part starting with T i have saved as a dynamic variable vars.transaction (e.g. vars.transaction == "T001045863113302101909"). I want to do a check if I have any files in this directory that contain my vars.transaction in the filename.

So I think I need to use sftp list connector, edit inline and use filename pattern. But as there is numbers before and after the Transaction part I am not sure what to put in the filename pattern. Something like *[#vars.transaction]*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the wildcard `*` along with your variable. Like `*#[vars.transaction]*` that will match all the files which has the `vars.transaction` in their name